# How do I fix CORS errors with next js 13

Tags: next.js

I'm making a GET request to this api and everything works fine in my localhost, but it gives cors errors when I deploy to Vercel.

how can solve this problem?

this is my /movies/router.js route

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import axios from "axios";

export async function GET(req) {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      url: process.env.URL,
    });
    return Response.json({ data: res.data }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return Response.json({ error: err }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next JS Blocked by CORS: Does not have HTTP ok status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645903/next-js-blocked-by-cors-does-not-have-http-ok-status)